# How to change the default background in listbox when it's pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am using a few listboxes to display a data that I get from a webservice. Also, I custimized the way the data is displayed. All is working OK.
The only problem I'm having is when I clicked at any ListBoxItem and them don't cover the entire hight of the listbox, the remaining space change its background to a default color like: WhiteSmoke or something like that.

I'm using the ItemDataTemplate to display the customize data and the ItemContainerStyle to change the way the listbox interact in any state like: pressed, selected, unfocus, etc.

Does anyone have an idea how to change this?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you've got the situation where your list items don't stretch all the way across the ListBox and so you're seeing the highlight underneath them, you can wipe out those colours with

```
  <ListBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />  
   </ListBox.Resources>
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your response. Your code works in a WPF Application. However, for a Windows Store App, the following piece of code doesn't work: {x:Static ...}. It says: Static is not supported in a Windows App project.

Comment: You can look at adding x:Static yourself (it's really not too hard), check out this post. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/93492aae-3c21-4a98-8c4f-05868283a096/how-to-replace-xstatic-in-metro-apps?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 1):

if you want to override the default background of the `listbox` write in the `xaml` of your `WPF`:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="thecoloryouwant" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: Hi apomene, thanks for your answer. As commented in Andy post your code works as well. However, for a Windows Store App, the following piece of code doesn't work: {x:Static ...}. It says: Static is not supported in a Windows App project.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the `Background` property of the `ListBoxItem`... you can do this like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```